# How to match sub part or super part of sentence in solr

Tags: solr

- I have installed solr 7.5
- Indexed multiple data as in below format with api

  `{
  "id":"doc_21",
  "contact":[9999999999],
  "description":"description goes here",
  "address":"address goes here",
  "rank":26,
  "business_id":21,
  "thumbs_down":1,
  "keywords":["web designer in New York",
    " web designer"],
  "title":"sample title"
  }`

Now if I am searching with

```
q:"keywords:\"best web designer in New York\""
```

then I don't get any record because **best** is not present in any record.

But what I want is it should first match with exact keyword then it should provide less matched record. like if I am searching with keyword **best web designer in New York** then solr must also return **web designer in New York**, **website designer in New York**, **designer in New York**, **in New York** in order of relevancy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as you've indexed your content in a field type that is properly tokenized  (the `text_general` field type included by default and used for text fields automagically in the schemaless mode) Solr already does that for you.

You can [use the `mm` parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm_MinimumShouldMatch_Parameter) to tell Solr that at least 70% of the terms in your query must match:

Append `&mm=70%` to your query string (and use the dismax or edismax query parsers):

> *Percentage*
>
> 70%
>
> Sets the minimum number of matching clauses to this percentage of the total number of optional clauses. The number computed from the percentage is rounded down and used as the minimum.

Comment: You're going to have to add a lot more detail to your question, with proper examples, to say why it's not working.

Comment: You're searching using `""` - this makes the query a phrase search. You're effectively telling Solr "I need these terms to be in order just as I type them". Use `edismax` and `q=best web designer in New York` together with `qf=keywords` (which field to query).

Comment: Its working but giving irrelevant result like from above keywords its returning **best carpenter in new york** on top. is there any solution to that

Comment: My guess is that that's one of the very few entries that have `best` in their title, which in that case is a highly relevant signal that that document might be an important match for your query string. The best option is to clean up those terms when indexing - i.e. add `best` and similar non-descriptive words (i.e. you don't consider them relevant for relevancy) as stop words in a stop word filter.

Comment: by adding "best", "in" stopwords and using mm=2 on above keyword seems resolve the problem. We are searching location based services and it also creating same problem some times. deciding mm is tough so will adding location also in stopword help us.

Comment: If you have other ways of determining location - possibly. But be aware that many people _will_ search for a specific company if they're named after a location, so you're going to have to have a second field without (or very low) boosting, so you at least return that document to users. Ignoring such an important part of the name might not be a good idea. In your example above, there can also be people that are named Best or where Best is an actual part of their registered company name - you still want people to be able to search for that. Have a field with the legal name, possibly?